# Different concept of 'days ago' used on reputation feed.

Tags: support

As far as I can tell, "1 day ago" doesn't quite mean the same thing on [the reputation feed](https://superuser.com/users/66040/pricechild?tab=reputation) as it does elsewhere, e.g. [activity](https://superuser.com/users/66040/pricechild?tab=activity).

On chat, [Daniel Beck](https://superuser.com/users/22317/daniel-beck) [says:](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/835261#835261)

> @PriceChild This one's easy. Rep feed
>   uses actual dates (i.e. April 15 =
>   today), while everything else seems to
>   use 24 hour periods (i.e. 23 hours ago
>   = today). That's why the post and activity feeds say your post on April
>   13 was yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

By "yesterday" we mean yesterday server-time, which is in UTC.  So for example if you're viewing your reputation at 12:05 UTC (8:05 EST, my local time for example), reputation changes that happened even 10 minutes ago are "yesterday" as far as the UTC day goes.

I don't follow the "1 day ago" part...because that particular string is never something we display, perhaps you can elaborate so I can clear that up?

The only difference between activity and reputation is that we show *by day*, since reputation is capped by day from **00:00:00 UTC** to **23:59:59 UTC**.  Actually rolling days in a perfect event days-ago fashion (relative to *now*) doesn't make sense there...because you would have no idea where events started/stopped/made up totals with respect to the reputation cap.  Because of this we group by UTC days, then show what the user's reputation was comprised of *that day*.

I hope that clears things up...if not please comment and I'll try again :)

Comment: Sorry by "1 day ago" i meant "1d", "2d" etc. It just seems odd time, using two different methods of calculating age across the site. The reputation cap definitely helps explain why though, thanks.